# Teechart with Candlestick for Delphi

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am using the TeeChart VCL Delphi module.   I am trying to plot a candlestick chart.   I have the following questions:

1. When I run the code it shows me the last date data on the right hand side.   However, the y-axis is not automatically scaling at all.   If I scroll backwards, it automatically adjust the y-axis scales.   However, if I go far to the right which is the end, it does not auto-scale the y-axis anymore.   What am I doing wrong?
2. The x-axis is the days of the week.  However, I have no data for the weekend.  It shows as empty space.  How do I remove that?
3. How do you change the cursor so it shows the date/time for the X,Y you choose?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Things work best here when each post contains just *one* question. You've asked three. Although they're all related to the same component, they're not really related to *each other* — they're three independent questions. Please [edit] this question to ask just one question, and then post your other two questions as new posts. There's no limit on the number of posts you're allowed to make, and separate questions makes sure that *each* question gets the attention it deserves.

Comment: Steema representatives routinely patrol Stackoverflow.  Since all the above are candlestick+LEGENDS issues, having three independant questions doesn't seem better to me. I know how to do all of the above with my TJvChart (which doesn't have candlesticks, only stacked bars) but not how to do this with TeeChart. I do think that visual issues should be accompanied by a screenshot. I can suggest that you should stop using Date-time as the X axis if you don't want gaps, just have labels for the items which are formatted strings for the dates. That will get rid of the gaps.

Comment: But @Warren, your comment *shows* why it's better to ask questions independently. If they'd been separate questions, you could have *answered* the second one. Instead, the information is buried in a comment.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.  I'm also thinking that if one user with 1 rep posts 3 questions all on minor variations of My Code Today with Tee Chart and Candlesticks two or all three will get closed and the user may get accused of spamming.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the code it shows me the last date data on the right hand
>   side. However, the y-axis is not automatically scaling at all. If I
>   scroll backwards, it automatically adjust the y-axis scales. However,
>   if I go far to the right which is the end, it does not auto-scale the
>   y-axis anymore. What am I doing wrong?

What about setting the Y axis (left axis) to be automatic? For example:

```
  Chart1.Axes.Left.Automatic:=True;
```

A more drastic solution would be also forcing the chart to repaint after adding each point.

```
  Series1.Add(value);
  Chart1.Draw;
```

If any of that helps please send us a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here. You can attach your files [here](http://www.steema.net/upload/).

> The x-axis is the days of the week. However, I have no data for the
>   weekend. It shows as empty space. How do I remove that?

You should do as in the *All Features\Welcome!\Chart Styles\Financial\Candle (OHLC)\Axis Labels no Weekends* example in the new features demo. This demo is included with registered and evaluation versions. Otherwise you can download it [here](http://www.steema.com/download/vcl).

> How do you change the cursor so it shows the date/time for the X,Y you
>   choose?

There are two examples in the demo that can help you on this:

*All Features\Welcome!\Tools\Annotation\Annotation Callout*

*All Features\Welcome!\Tools\Cursor\Synchronizing Two*

Comment: @user2212281 standalone compiled demos don't include source code. For demos sources you should download the evaluation version where full demo projects are included.